# Does Julia has an keyword equivalent to Python's __del__

Tags: julia

`__del__` is like a destructor called when an object is garbage collected. 
For example , when a DB connection is out of scope it `__del__` method can be used to release itself from a pool etc.

Does Julia has a similar keyword / conecpt.

Answer (score 3):

More or less: [`finalizer(f, x)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.finalizer) registers a function `f` to be called when the *object* `x` is garbage collected.  If you want to always register the same function for all objects of a certain type, you can do so in an inner constructor.